# How to deal with more complex criteria sorting/grouping items in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'v stumbled upon a problem that i am struggling with while learning python, and
In my example, i have a list populated with objects (these objects are lists themselves that can be accessed individually)

```
list_objects =[object5, object2, object4, object1, ojbject3, object6, object7, object8, object9]
```

Each object has functions that points to another object:

> - input0()
> - input1()
> - output()

Some of the objects can happen to be connected to each other, e.g. it can happen to be:

```
object5.input0() == object4 # object5 input points to object4
```

And sometimes it can happen that some of the object are connected to other object that are not in `list_objects` like:

```
object4.input0() == objectA
```

or like:

```
object4.input1() == objectM1
```

And finally, it can happen that multiple objects are connected to each other like this (i'll try to explain it as best as i can with some drawing):

```
objectA
   | # this is output of objectA
   |
   v # this is input0 of object4
object4 < # input1 of object 4 
   |      \
   |       -- objectM1
   v      /
object5 < # input1 of object 4
   |
   |
   v
objectB
   |
   |
   v
object1 <
   |     \
   |      \
   v       \
object2 <--- objectM2
   |       /
   |      /
   v     /
object3 <
   |
   |
   v
object6 <
   |     \
   |      \
   v       \
object8 <--- objectM3
   |       /|
   |      / |
   v     /  |
object7 <   |
   |       /
   |      /
   v     /
object9 <
   |
   |
   v
#(here is None or it goes on)
```

And now the desired result is that i somehow filter the objects in `list_objects` and get only the first and last objects that are connected to each other like this:

```
new_list =[[object4, object5], [object1, object3], [object6, object9]]
```

the order here is of importance.. i need to get the first object first in the list, and the last to get at the end as presented.

I hope i explained the problem clear enough.

it seems i can't find good solution for this, i have tried double for loops and while loops.. but i think going with this i will have to run multiple times through to get the result what i need, it got a mess couple of times with those approaches and i gave up after a whole day trying.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a graph on your hands, I suggest you treat it like one.

First model is as an undirected graph, and look for cycles containing your external nodes. Find the longest cycle for each of these nodes.

Then look at the directed graph (pretty much what you have in your drawing) to find the two nodes you want to report for each cycle.